# Can I save Kinect game progress without internet?

Tags: xbox-network, kinect

When my Xbox 360 is not connected to the Internet, for certain Kinect games I am only able to log in using guest mode. Thus I am unable to save game progress. Every time I play again I start from fresh.

But when I play the game that came in the Kinect bundle—*Kinect Adventures*—I am able to log into my profile and save game.

Do all Kinect games except Kinect Adventures require access to the Internet to log into my profile?  Is there a way to save Kinect games progress on Xbox Console HDD?

Comment: Can you please specify what game(s) are giving you trouble?

Answer (score 1):

**Kinect Adventures does not need internet when playing.**

Basically, when you sign in to Kinect Adventures, your logging in to your account, but not Xbox Live.

Some games, on the other hand, require you to sign in to Xbox Live to save because they are online games. So my assumption is that you do not have an Xbox Live Gold account.

So you can save any game that requires internet, but you would have to purchase Xbox Live Gold.

Answer (score 0):

Kinect games are just like controller-based games. You can sign in while you are offline and play portions of a game that don't require Internet access and save your progress (provided you picked your Hard Drive or Removable Drive as the medium when asked).

As I am not sure which game you are having trouble with, I can't really help you specifically with any game.

Comment: Two tips related to this: 1) Be sure you go through the steps to setup the facial recognition, otherwise the games may log you in as guest because they do not recognize you 2) When in doubt, use a controller.  If you press the XBox button on your controller, you should get an option to "Sign In", even if facial recognition failed.  Most Kinect games don't have much of an online component, other than DLC, so I doubt it is required in your case.